# query a database with psycopg2 and want to get a readable duration/interval

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql-9.1, intervals, psycopg2, bottle

I query the database with psycopg2 like:

```
cur.execute("SELECT SUM(duration) AS total FROM entry WHERE mission = %s", (mission,))
total = cur.fetchone()
```

where the **mission** is a given string.
If I try to print **total** I get a string like:

> (datetime.timedelta(1, 21840),)

So I want to parse it to a human readable string like:

> 1d 6h 4min

Thanks for answers ;)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution by myself and here it is (it's much too simple...):

As mentioned above 'total' has the value:

```
>>> total = (datetime.timedelta(1, 21840),)
```

Just type

```
>>> total = total[0]
```

So I get what I want:

```
>>> print(total)
>>> 1 day, 6:04:00
```